# Events won't appear on php calendar

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, calendar

I've made a php events calendar which is working and i can switch between months, however when i add an event into my database it doesnt appear on my calendar. Any help most appreciated.

**Code:**
show calendar.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="calstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function initialCalendar(){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "calendar_start.php";
    var currentTime = new Date ();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    showmonth = month;
    showyear = year;
    var vars= "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar"). innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function next_month() {
    var nextmonth = showmonth + 1;
    if(nextmonth > 12) {
        nextmonth = 1;
        showyear = showyear+1;
    }
    showmonth = nextmonth;
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "calendar_start.php";
    var vars= "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar"). innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function last_month() {
    var lastmonth = showmonth - 1;
    if(lastmonth < 1 ) {
        lastmonth = 12;
        showyear = showyear-1;
    }
    showmonth = lastmonth;
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "calendar_start.php";
    var vars= "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar"). innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function overlay() {
    el = document.getElementById("overlay");
    el.style.display = (el.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
    el. = document.getElementById("events");
    el.style.display = (el.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
    el. = document.getElementById("eventsBody");
    el.style.display = (el.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
}
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function show_details(theId) {
    var deets = )theId.id);
    el = document.getElementById("overlay");
    el.style.display = (el.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
    el. = document.getElementById("events");
    el.style.display = (el.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "events.php";
    var vars = "deets="+deets;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange= function() {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("events").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.get ElementById("events").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialCalendar();">
<div id="showCalendar"> </div>
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="events"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

calendar_start.php

```
<?php
$showmonth = $_POST['showmonth'];
$showyear = $_POST['showyear'];
$showmonth= preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $showmonth);
$showyear= preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $showyear);

$day_count = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $showmonth, $showyear);
$pre_days = date('w', mktime(0,0,0, $showmonth, 1, $showyear));
$post_days = (6-(date('w', mktime(0,0,0, $showmonth, $day_count, $showyear))));

echo '<div id="calendar_wrap">';
echo '<div class="title_bar">';
echo '<div class="previous_month"><input name="button" type="submit" value="Previous Month" onClick="javascript:last_month();"></div>';
echo '<div class="show_month">'  . date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $showmonth)) . ' ' . $showyear . '</div>';
echo '<div class="next_month"><input name="button" type="submit" value="Next Month" onClick="javascript:next_month();"></div>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="week_days">';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Sun</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Mon</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Tues</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Wed</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Thur</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Fri</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Sat</div>';
echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
echo '</div>';

if ($pre_days != 0) { 
    for($i=1; $i<=$pre_days; $i++) {
        echo '<div class="non_cal_day"></div>';
    }
}
include ("connect.php");
for ($i=1; $i<= $day_count; $i++) {
    $date = $i.'/'.$showmonth.'/'.$showyear;
$query = "Select id FROM events WHERE evDate = '$date'";
$num_rows = 0;
if($result = mysql_query($query)) {
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
}
    if($num_rows > 0) {
        $event = "<input name='$date' type='submit' value='Details' id='$date'
onClick='javascript:show_details(this);'>";
    }
    echo '<div class="cal_day">';
    echo '<div class="day_heading">' . $i . '</div>';
    if($num_rows != 0) { echo "<div class='openings'><br/>" . $event . "</div>";}
    echo '</div>';
}

if ($post_days !=0) {
    for($i=1; $i<=$post_days; $i++) {
        echo '<div class="non_cal_day"></div>';
    }
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

events.php

```
<?php
$deets = $_POST['deets'];
$deets = preg_replace('#[^0-9/]#i', '', $deets);

include ("connect.php");

$events = '';
$query = mysql_query('SELECT description FROM events WHERE evdate ="'.$deets.'"');
$num_rows= mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($num_rows > 0) {
    $events.= '<div id="eventsControl"><button onMouseDown="overlay()">Close</button><br /><b> ' . $deets . '</b><br /><br /></div>';

    while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $desc = $row['description'];
        $events .='<div id="eventsBody"> . $desc .'<br /><hr><br /></div>';
    }
}
echo $events;
?>
```

connect.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Familease");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
 ?>
```

Plus a style sheet which should work fine. Sorry for the massive code dump

Answer (score 0):

Your following code shows some syntax error

```
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $desc = $row['description'];
        $events .='<div id="eventsBody"> . $desc .'<br /><hr><br /></div>';
    }
```

Should be as

```
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $desc = $row['description'];
        $events .='<div id="eventsBody">'.$desc .'<br /><hr><br /></div>';
    }
```

Comment: Thats one part of the issue, can you check if your query is returning any data ?